# How to read content of files inside Zip file which is inside a Zip file

Tags: java, zip

Zip Structure:-

```
OuterZip.zip--|
              |--Folder1---InnerZip.zip--|
                                         |--TxtFile1.txt    // Requirement is to read content of txt file 
                                         |--TxtFile2.txt    // Without extracting any of zip file
```

Now i am able to read the names of txt files but not contents of that.

Code:-

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("Outer.zip");
ZipEntry ze;
for (Enumeration e = zip.entries(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
    ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(zip.getInputStream(entry));
    while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(ze.getName());                                 //Can read names of txtfiles, Not contents
        zip.getInputStream(ze); // It is giving null
    }
}
}
```

PS:- 1. Wants to do it without extracting any of zip in file system.
      2. Already seen some answers on SOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile("Outer.zip");
...
zip.getInputStream(ze); // It is giving null
```

Contents of `ze` (e.g. `TxtFile1.txt`) are part of `InnerZip.zip` not `Outer.zip` (represented by `zip`), hence `null`.

I'd use recursion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     String name = "Outer.zip";
     FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(name));
     readZip(input, name);
}

public static void readZip(final InputStream in, final String name) throws IOException {
    final ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(in);
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (entry.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".zip")) {
            readZip(zin, name + "/" + entry.getName());
        } else {
            readFile(zin, entry.getName());
        }
    }
}

private static void readFile(final InputStream in, final String name) {
    String contents = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)).lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    System.out.println(String.format("Contents of %s: %s", name, contents));
}
```

**0.** `while (...)` we are iterating through whole all entries.

**1.** (`if (.endsWith(".zip"))`) in case we encounter another zip we call recursively itself (`readZip()`) and go to step **0.**

**2.** (`else`) otherwise we print the contents of the file (assuming text files here).